# In cypress headless mode tests failed to pick up the settings provided in index.js

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

On click on some button in our testing site, system should navigate to MYOB login page. But while running the test in headless mode this is not happening and display below page ( please refer the screenshot). In test runner mode, initially I saw this error, but after adding `--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies` in the index.js, test successfully navigates to MYOB site and I was able to proceed further. Any idea why the above settings is not applied for headless mode.

[image]

Cypress version: 6.6.0
Git bash : 2.28.0
OS: Windows 10 64 bit operating system
cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": 2.5.5

Running the below command from Git bash:

```
CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://some-test-url/book/ npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@experimental' --config experimentalSourceRewriting=true GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/book/test-booking.feature' --headless --browser chrome



const testStore = {};
    module.exports = (on, config) => {
        on('file:preprocessor', cucumber()),
            on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
                if (browser.name === 'chrome' && browser.isHeadless) {
                    launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu');
                    return launchOptions
                }
    
                if (browser.name === 'chrome' || browser.name === 'edge' || browser.isHeadless) {
                    launchOptions.args.push('--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies') // bypass 401 unauthorised access on chromium-based browsers
                    return launchOptions
                }
    
                if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
                   // launch chrome using incognito
                   launchOptions.args.push(' --incognito')
                   return launchOptions
                }
            });
    
        on('task', {
            copySomeData({ name, value }) {
                console.log(name, value)
                testStore[name] = value
         
                return true
            },
        });
    
        on('task', {
            getSomeData(name) {
                return testStore[name]
            },
        });
    
    };
```

Comment: If you are testing in Incognito Mode, be aware that the default setting for Incognito Mode is to block third-party cookies. This can lead to behavior that appears similar to cross-site cookies being blocked due to lack of a SameSite attribute. This setting can be changed on Incognito Mode's New Tab Page, or in chrome://settings/cookies. source: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug